Confusion about bound surface charge density
I am taking a course in ElectroMagnetism and we are now studying electromagnetic fields in matter. We were taught that the total charge is separated into free charge and bound charge:
$$\rho = \rho_b + \rho_f$$
We also defined the polarization by
$$\rho_b = -\nabla\cdot\mathbf{P}$$
Then we assumed the matter was neutral so that:
$$\iiint\limits_{\Omega}\mathrm{d}V\rho_b + \iint\limits_{\partial\Omega}\mathrm{d}S\sigma_b = 0$$
By plugging in the definition of polarization and using Gauss's theorem we get:
$$ \iiint\limits_{\Omega}\mathrm{d}V\rho_b = -\iiint\limits_{\Omega}\mathrm{d}V\nabla\cdot\mathbf{P} = -\iint\limits_{\partial\Omega}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}\cdot\mathbf{P} = -\iint\limits_{\partial\Omega}\mathrm{d}S \sigma_b $$
From this we can conclude that:
$$\sigma_b = \hat{\mathbf{s}}\cdot\mathbf{P}$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{s}}$ is a unit normal to the surface. However, looking at the definition of the polarization:
$$\rho_b = -\nabla\cdot\mathbf{P}$$
We can integrate this over a small volume that encapsulates the surface and apply Gauss's theorem to get the jump in the polarization similar to how we relate the jump of the electric field near a surface to the charge density using Gauss's law:
$$\sigma_b = -\hat{\mathbf{s}}\cdot (\mathbf{P}^{\text{out}} - \mathbf{P}^{\text{in}}) = -\Delta P^{\perp}$$
These two formulas confuse me because one has a minus sign and the other one doesn't. From the first formula, I would infer that $\sigma_b = \Delta P^{\perp}$ without the minus sign which is wrong.
Both formulas seem correct. The first formula (without the minus) I also found on Wikipedia and Griffith's book with a similar derivation. I couldn't find any mention of the second formula online or in the literature, but this is what we were taught in the practice session (not in the lecture where we learned the first formula), and it seems to be correct (+ It's derivation uses Gauss's law exactly the same to how we find the discontinuity of the electric field near a charged surface so it looks convincing). In our homework assignment, we were told to find the bound and free charge on the surface of a given configuration and then verify that the total charge indeed gives the potential we found for this configuration before and the correct solution uses the second formula with the minus sign.
I can't understand if these two formulas are equivalent or if they are contradicting each other. The first formula was derived with Gauss's theorem which uses a normal which is directed outside the surface so there shouldn't be any minus sign. Can somebody explain to me why these two formulas are equivalent and what I am doing wrong?
